# Mean field equations in the BCS theory of superconductivity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

In BCS theory, one takes the model Hamiltonian

$$
\sum_{k\sigma} (E_k-\mu)c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma} +\sum_{kk'}V_{kk'}c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}
$$

This Hamiltonian clearly conserves particle number. Thus, we expect the ground state to have a definite particle number. It's possible the ground state is degenerate, but that could be lifted by perturbing $\mu$.

Then, one makes a mean field approximation. One replaces $$c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}$$

with $$\langle c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger\rangle c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}+c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger \langle c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}\rangle-\langle c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger\rangle \langle c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}\rangle$$

This doesn't make any sense to me. This seems to be saying that we know the terms $c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger$ and $c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}$ don't fluctuate much around their mean values. But we also know that in the actual ground state, the mean values are given by $\langle c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}\rangle=\langle c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger\rangle=0$ since the ground state will have definite particle number. Thus the fluctuations about the mean value aren't small compared to the mean value.

How can this mean field treatment be justified?

Comment: Maybe this helps : http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02731446

Comment: @JahanClaes I think I start understanding your problem. Is it because in the superconducting construction, you feel that one continues to suppose the ground state $\left|N\right\rangle $ is a Fermi sea, for which one should clearly get $\left\langle N\right|cc\left|N\right\rangle =0$, whereas one supposes in contrary that $\left\langle N-2\right|cc\left|N\right\rangle \propto\Delta\neq0$ when constructing the BCS order parameter $\Delta$ ? Is that your problem ?

Comment: @JahanClaes Otherwise, an other way to justify the mean-field approximation is given in this answer : http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/257639/16689. It is the same thing as below [http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/257639/16689]. Questions about the symmetry breaking get partial answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133780/superconductor-symmetry-breaking/134410#134410 and question about particle number conservation get partial answer here : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44565/what-does-particle-number-conservation-mean-in-condensed-matter-physics/69490#69490

Comment: But if you want to understand why one must enlarge the class of accessible ground state(s) when discussing second order symmetry breaking, and in particular for the case of superconductivity, then you first have to restate your question, because it is not clear at all (it took me 3 days to understand it ...), then I may give an answer if I have time to write it. This question is indeed interesting, and I never tried to put words on it :-)

Comment: Bout mean-field again, there is also the Ginzburg criterion, which helps understanding why mean-field works in superconductors : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298327/16689

Comment: @FraSchelle I don't think the ground state $|N\rangle$ is necessarily a Fermi sea. But I do think the ground state should be SOMETHING with definite particle number, $|N\rangle$, even if it doesn't look like a Fermi sea.

Comment: @FraSchelle I looked through the answers you linked, and I think the thing I don't understand is this line, from one of your answers: "Saying that the number of particles is not conserved is an abuse of language, since the total number of electrons is the same in both the normal and superconducting phases...But that's true that some electrons are disappearing in a sense. As I said in the introduction: they are transmuted in Cooper pairs." I don't understand how the electrons "disappear" when they become Cooper pairs, or how that works out mathematically.

Comment: Well, it's just a matter of convention, if you call an electron a correlation function of charge $e$, then a particle of charge $2e$ is not an electron. *Electron* in a metal are in fact Landau quasi-particle of a genuine electron surrounded by bosonic excitations like e.g. phonon. That's the basics of condensed matter. In quantum optics it's called a dressed particle. Anyways, these *electron* still form a ground state which is the Fermi surface. But the Fermi surface is not stable with respect to one interaction : the virtual exchange of a phonon. This is called the Cooper instability.

Comment: It results in the formation of Cooper pairs. In 1954, Cooper calls them some bound states of two electrons, now we call them correlations of charge $2e$, but they are still the same, and certainly no more *electron* in the sense of Landau. But they are still quasi-partile if you wish. It's just some confusing nomenclature.  Anyways, since the total charge of the system is conserved, and that *electron* now combines to form Cooper pairs, the number of *electron* is not conserved ... That's what I meant with the citation you took from my other answer. Is that more clear now ?

Comment: I gave my thought about the enlargement of ground states due to symmetry breaking, I hope it's clear enough. I continue to think your question is only poorly related to the mean field treatment itself, and so you should change the title of your question.

Comment: In the thermodynamic limit the mean field solutions are pure states whereas the gauge invariant ground states are mixed states .

Comment: A lot of the confusion here comes from people taking the mean field approach too literally. No matter how you count, the number of electrons in a superconductor is fixed. Pairing, etc. cannot change that. However, dealing with particle conservation is very unwieldy (think about dealingwith particle conservation in the microcanonical ensemble of a Fermi gas without a chemical potential!). I think the best reference on this issue of particle conservation is Tony Leggett's textbook "Quantum Liquids". He goes through the entire BCS calculation without forgoing electron number conservation.

Comment: @user157879 I had heard that Leggett didn't use the grand canonical ensemble but didn't know the reference. Thanks, I will check it out!

Answer (score 12):

> First, why do we choose those terms to put the brakets around? Do we
>   somehow know that these are the terms that won't fluctuate much?

The heuristic motivation is that the superconductivity phenomenon can be understood as the non-relativistic analog of the Higgs mechanism for the EM $U_{\text{EM}}(1)$ (this idea explains the main properties of the superconductor, such as absence of resistivity, magnetic field expulsion and other). For the Higgs mechanism one need a condensate of some particles. In the solid body, the only candidates are electrons. The simplest choice of the condensate is the scalar condensate (very-very heuristically, we require the Galilei invariance into the superconductor). Therefore the only allowed simplest scalar bounded state $|\psi\rangle$ is constructed from the electron pair with zero total spin, which can be imagine as two fermions moving in opposite directions:
$$
|\psi\rangle = c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf k, \uparrow}c^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf k, \downarrow}|0\rangle
$$
This is indeed realized when we calculate the four-fermion vertex in the microscopic theory of electron-phonon interactions. Indeed, we start from the interaction Hamiltonian
$$
H_{\text{int}} = g\psi^{\dagger}\psi \varphi, 
$$ 
where $\psi$ is electron field, while $\varphi$ is phonon field, and assume the second order in $g$ diagrams of electron-electron scattering; let's denote their momenta as $\mathbf p_{i}$. After tedious calculations of the corresponding diagram one finds that the vertex $\Gamma^{(4)}(\mathbf{p}_{1},\mathbf{p}_{2},\mathbf{p}_{3},\mathbf{p}_{4})$ (with $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{p}_{1} + \mathbf{p}_{2}$) has the pole at zero momentum $\mathbf q$ and zero total spin of fermions $1,2$ and $3,4$ or ($1,4$ and $2,3$). The pole quickly disappears once one enlarges $|\mathbf q|$.

Finally, since 4-fermion vertex is expressed through two-particles Green $G^{(2)}$ function, then the presence of the pole in $\Gamma^{(4)}$ means the presence of the pole in $G^{(2)}$. This means that bounded states of electrons appear.

> Second, why can't we just immediately say $\langle c_{-k'\downarrow}c_{k'\uparrow}\rangle=\langle c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger\rangle=0$ since we know the ground state will
>   have definite particle number, and $c_{-k'\downarrow} c_{k'\uparrow}$
>   and $c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger$ don't conserve
>   particle number?

*(Added)* Let's again use the idea of Higgs mechanism. It is clearly that the number of particles isn't strictly conserved in superconducting state. Really, because of the SSB of $U_{\text{EM}}(1)$ group the system loses the definition of the conserved particle number (being associated to the global phase invariance current) in the ground state.

Microscopically the formation of the condensate is argued in a following way: the presence of the two-fermions bounded states leads to instability of the electron gas inside the superconductor, and fermions are converted in Cooper pairs. Really, for bosons the lowest energy state can be filled by infinitely many number of particles, while for fermions this is not true due to Pauli principle. This (under some assumptions, see below) leads to formation of new vacuum state on which the operator $\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\mathbf k,\uparrow}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf k, \downarrow}$ has non-zero VEV:
$$
\langle \text{vac} | \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\mathbf p,\uparrow}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf p, \downarrow}|\text{vac}\rangle = \Psi \neq 0
$$
It's not hard to construct this state:
$$
|\text{vac}\rangle = \prod_{\mathbf k = \mathbf k_{1}...k_{\frac{N}{2}}}(u_{\mathbf k} + v_{\mathbf k}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\mathbf k,\uparrow}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf k, \downarrow})|0\rangle, \quad |v_{\mathbf k}|^{2} + |u_{\mathbf k}|^{2} = 1
$$
This state called **the coherent state** really doesn't have definite number of particles.

For the particles number operator $\hat{N} = \sum_{\mathbf k}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\mathbf k,\uparrow}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf k, \downarrow}$ the VEV $\langle \text{vac}|\hat{N}|\text{vac}\rangle$ is
$$
\tag 1 N = \langle \text{vac}|\hat{N}|\text{vac}\rangle \sim \sum_{\mathbf k}|v_{\mathbf k}|^{2},
$$
**Why the number of particles is not so indefinite**

However, the root $\sqrt{\Delta N^{2}}$ of quadratic deviation from
while the quadratic deviation $\langle \text{vac}|(\hat{N} - N)^{2}|\text{vac}\rangle$ is
$$
\tag 2 \Delta N^{2} = \langle \text{vac}|(\hat{N} - N)^{2}|\text{vac}\rangle = \sum_{\mathbf k}|u_{\mathbf k}|^{2}|v_{\mathbf k}|^{2}
$$
is negligible in the limit of large particle number (and volume). Really, both of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are proportional to the volume $V$ (note only one summation over wave-numbers $\mathbf k$ in $(2)$), and hence $\sqrt{\Delta N^{2}} \sim \sqrt{V}$ which is negligible in the large volume limit. This argument is seemed to be first published in the BCS article.

*(Added)* This means that the state of superconductor with good accuracy can be projected on the state with definite particle number $N$. Precisely, define the phase dependent ground state
$$
|\text{vac}(\theta)\rangle = |\text{vac}[c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf k, \uparrow/\downarrow} \to c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf k, \uparrow/\downarrow}e^{-i\theta}]\rangle
$$ 
The state with definite particle number $N$ is defined as
$$
|N\rangle = \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta e^{i\hat{N}\theta}|\text{vac}(\theta)\rangle
$$

Comment: I understand why once you solve the mean field equations you get a state with non-definite particle number. But why doesn't imply that we've made a very bad mistake, since we know the ground state does have a definite particle number?

Comment: @JahanClaes : The fact that the total number of particles has negligible fluctuations for large system means that the system state tends to the state with definite number of particles $N$ (see an edit of my answer).

Comment: But when you're choosing the operators $c^\dagger c^\dagger$ and $cc$ to expand around the mean field, isn't that invalid because their mean values are necessarily zero before the mean field approximation?

Comment: The expectation value of $\left\langle cc\right\rangle \neq0$ in a superconductor. That's precisely what makes a superconductor superconducts ... in addition to provide the Meissner effect, Josephson effect, Little-Parks effect, and so on. In superconductor, one does not take the expectation value $\left\langle N\right|cc\left|N\right\rangle =0$, with $\left|N\right\rangle$ the state with $N$ electrons, but $\left\langle N\right|cc\left|N+2\right\rangle \neq0$. There is in general no reason why this should be vanishing, but when it is, the system is not superconducting.

Comment: More details can be found in any textbook on superconductivity. @NameYYY gave full details about the BCS Ansatz (the fermionic coherent state in her/his answer), and the discussion about non conservation of particle number in the ground state of a superconductor. You may find some of my answers on related questions useful as well, as e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/134410/16689 http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69490/16689 or http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284355/16689

Comment: @FraSchelle I'm asking for an explanation of why $\langle cc\rangle\neq 0$, since naively all you need to prove $\langle cc\rangle= 0$ is that $H$ conserves particle number.

Comment: $\left\langle cc\right\rangle \neq 0$ because the ground state is no more a Fermi sea, but a superfluid made of Cooper pairs. Even when the Hamiltonian conserves the number of particle, its ground state may not. This mechanism is called a spontaneous symmetry breaking. By definition of a spontaneous symmetry breaking, the two sentences "$\left\langle cc\right\rangle \neq 0$" and "the system is superconducting" are strictly equivalent. $\left\langle cc\right\rangle $ is called the order parameter of the superconducting phase. I strongly suggest to open any textbook about superconductivity.

Comment: I have the feeling your problem is what you never wrote : usually, the notation $\left\langle O\right\rangle $ is a shorthand for $\left\langle \phi\right|O\left|\phi\right\rangle $, with $\left|\phi\right\rangle$ the ground state of the system. So please ask yourself : what is the ground state of a superconductor ? I gave you some links for more details. Once you will get some idea about Cooper pairing, Cooper instability (which requires some knowledge about Fermi liquid), I think you will understand why $\left\langle N\right|cc\left|N+2\right\rangle \neq0$ in a superconductor.

Comment: @FraSchelle But all the calculations for the ground state of a superconductor are based on the assumption that the mean field treatment applies. Obviously once you make the mean field approximation, the resulting Hamiltonian doesn't conserve particle number. But the mean field approximation itself seems invalid.

Comment: @FraSchelle I don't think spontaneous symmetry breaking can be the cause of this, since even if the ground state is degenerate, that degeneracy must take place in a definite particle number sector. Or if it doesn't, it will upon perturbing $\mu$.

Comment: @FraSchelle In other words, for almost every $\mu$, even if there is degeneracy that is broken via spontaneous symmetry breaking, that degeneracy takes place in a subspace w/ definite particle number.

Comment: Ok, let be quick about it ! Do you have a better explanation for superconductivity ? Please propose it ! Otherwise, I suggest you to open any textbook and to understand their purpose before starting polemics about everything you misunderstand. Of course the mean field approximation works, of course the ground state breaks the conservation of particle (simply because particles transmute from fermions to bosons), of course it is a spontaneous symmetry breaking mechanism. (...)

Comment: (...) It took more than 50 years to understand all these details, but feel free to contradict all of them if you prefer. That's how science progress actually. To all these points I already gave you some links for more details. Did you at least open them before continuing your polemics ?

Comment: @FraSchelle I'm not saying I'm smarter than Bardeen. I'm saying I don't understand why something happens, and I'd like a simple explanation why.

Comment: @FraSchelle I just fundamentally don't understand *how* to justify the mean field treatment, or why it works. If the answer is "no one knows why, but we know it works," that's fine, but I imagine there is a better justification than that?

Comment: @FraSchelle I don't think the answer is just spontaneous symmetry breaking, but I'd welcome an answer that proved me wrong.

Comment: Hi Jahan, while the above answer is correct you are justified in not being completely satisfied with the normal treatment of number conservation in BECs/superconductors and the relation to SSB. I strongly suggest you take a look at Leggett's book Quantum Liquids, chapter 2, which has a very interesting discussion about this.

Comment: @Rococo It would be pleasant if you do not mess up everything ! Jahan Claea is asking for the explicit case of a BCS superconductor, Leggett discussion (though of intrinsic great quality and interest) is about BEC ! Nothing to do. 1) The order of the phase transition is not known in a BEC, 2) An order parameter can not be clearly defined (points 1 and 2 comes together). In a BCS superconductor, 1) The phase transition is of second order, so 2) The notion of an order parameter exists, it is either the number of Cooper pairs, or the phase rigidity of the condensate (...)

Comment: (...) the two orders parameters are indeed the same thing, since one usually writes a superconductor as an Abelian Higgs model, with order parameter $\Delta \propto \sqrt{N} e^{i\varphi}$, with $N$ the number of Cooper pairs, and $\varphi$ the phase rigidity mentionned above.

Comment: @FraSchelle, the number of electrons in a material above and below the superconducting transition is fixed. Proof: charge conservation. The number of cooper pairs however is not fixed. There is plenty of discussion on number conservation and why it holds, but still can be put aside for calculations dating back even to Robert Schrieffer's thesis.

Comment: @user157879 It's all about terminology. I would prefer to say that the number of charges is conserved (it's even a tautology since one uses the charge conservation...) but not the number of electrons, seen as quasi-particles, because the formation of the Cooper pair quasi-particle let two electrons quasi-particles disappearing. Important point is to know what one means by electrons, and it seems to me it's all the problem of the OP. Anyways, I'd welcome a reference about the calculation of the number of charges (not electrons) above and below the phase transition.

Answer (score 10):

After some thoughts, I think an other (and hopefully better) answer might go along the following lines, perhaps more rigorous. Nevertheless, I will not give the full mathematical details, since they require too much writing.

At the heart of perturbative treatment of many-body problems lies the Wick theorem. For two body interaction of fermionic nature, it states that

$$\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}c_{3}c_{4}\right\rangle =\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\rangle \left\langle c_{3}c_{4}\right\rangle -\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{3}\right\rangle \left\langle c_{2}^{\dagger}c_{4}\right\rangle +\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{4}\right\rangle \left\langle c_{2}^{\dagger}c_{3}\right\rangle $$

As any theorem it can be rigorously proven. In fact, the proof is not that cumbersome, and I refer to

- Danielewicz, P. (1984). *Quantum theory of nonequilibrium processes, I*. [Annals of Physics, 152(2), 239–304](http://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(84)90092-7). See Appendix A.
- Gaudin, M. (1960). *Une démonstration simplifiée du théorème de Wick en mécanique statistique*. [Nuclear Physics, 15, 89–91](http://doi.org/10.1016/0029-5582(60)90285-6). In french.

where the demonstration is the same in both papers. The key point is that one needs a Gaussian state to demonstrate the theorem, namely one needs a statistical operator in the form $\rho=e^{-\sum\epsilon_{n}c_{n}^{\dagger}c_{n}}$. In any other case the Wick's decomposition does not work (or at least I'm not aware of such a decomposition). Importantly, the demonstration in the above references uses only the anti-commutation properties between the $c$'s operators. So any time one has a statistical average made over Gaussian states of some anti-commuting (i.e. fermionic) operators, the Wick's theorem applies.

Now, the strategy of the mean-field treatment is the following. Write the Hamiltonian (I use the symbol $\sim$ to withdraw integrals and/or sums over all degrees of freedom)

$$H\sim H_{0}+c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}c_{3}c_{4} \sim H_{0}+H_{\text{m.f.}}+\delta H$$

with $H_{0}$ the free particle Hamiltonian (which can be written in the form $H_{0}\sim\epsilon_{n}c_{n}^{\dagger}c_{n}$ in a convenient basis), $H_{\text{m.f.}}=\Delta c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}+\Delta^{\ast}c_{3}c_{4}$ the mean-field Hamiltonian, and $\delta H=c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}c_{3}c_{4}-H_{\text{m.f.}}$ the correction to the mean-field Hamiltonian.

The mean-field Hamiltonian can be diagonalised using a Bogliubov transformation, namely, one can write

$$H_{0}+H_{\text{m.f.}}=\sum_{n}\epsilon_{n}\gamma_{n}^{\dagger}\gamma_{n}$$

where the $\gamma$'s are some fermionic operators verifying

$$c_{i}=u_{ik}\gamma_{k}+v_{ik}\gamma_{k}^{\dagger}\\c_{i}^{\dagger}=u_{ik}^{\ast}\gamma_{k}^{\dagger}+v_{ik}^{\ast}\gamma_{k}$$

note: there are some constraints imposed on the $u$'s and $v$'s in order for the above Bogoliubov transformation to preserve the (anti-)commutation relation ; in that case one talks about canonical transformation, see

- Fetter, A. L., & Walecka, J. D. (1971). *Quantum theory of many-particle systems*. MacGraw-Hill.

for more details about canonical transformations. Once one knows a few properties of the mean-field ground state, one can show that $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left\langle \delta H\right\rangle \rightarrow0$ when $N$ represents the number of fermionic degrees of freedom, and the statistical average $\left\langle \cdots\right\rangle $ is performed over the mean-field ground state, namely $\left\langle \cdots\right\rangle =\text{Tr}\left\{ e^{-\sum\epsilon_{n}\gamma_{n}^{\dagger}\gamma_{n}}\cdots\right\} $. See

- De Gennes, P.-G. (1999). *Superconductivity of metals and alloys*. Advanced Book Classics, Westview Press

for a clear derivation of this last result. In fact deGennes shows how to choose the $u$ and $v$ in order for the Bogoliubov transformation to diagonalise the mean-field Hamiltonian, and then he shows that this choice leads to the best approximation of the zero-temperature ground state of the interacting (i.e. full) Hamiltonian. The idea to keep in mind is that the mean-field treatment works. Up to now, we nevertheless restrict ourself to operator formalism. When dealing with quantum field theory and its methods, one would prefer to use the Wick's theorem.

So, now we come back to the Wick's decomposition. One can manipulate the statistical average and show that

$$\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\rangle =\text{Tr}\left\{ \rho c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\} \\=\text{Tr}\left\{ e^{-\varepsilon_{n}c_{n}^{\dagger}c_{n}}c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\} =\text{Tr}\left\{ c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}e^{-\varepsilon_{n}c_{n}^{\dagger}c_{n}}\right\} =e^{-2\varepsilon_{n}}\text{Tr}\left\{ e^{-\varepsilon_{n}c_{n}^{\dagger}c_{n}}c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\} \\=e^{-2\varepsilon_{n}}\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\rangle =0$$

using the cyclic property of the trace and the Bakker-Campbell-Hausdorf formula to pass the exponential from right to left of the two creation operators. The quantity should be zero because it is equal to itself multiplied by a positive quantity $e^{-2\varepsilon_{n}}$. The manipulation is the same as one does for the Wick's theorem, so I do not write it fully, check the above references.

The conclusion is that clearly, the quantity $\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\rangle $ is zero in the Wick's decomposition. But due to the Cooper problem (or what we learned from the mean-field treatment), one knows that we should not take the statistical average over the free fermions $e^{-\sum\varepsilon_{n}c_{n}^{\dagger}c_{n}}$, but over the Bogoliubov quasi-particles $e^{-\sum\epsilon_{n}\gamma_{n}^{\dagger}\gamma_{n}}$, since they represent the approximately true (in the limit of large $N$ it is exact) ground state. Say differently, the Fermi surface is not the ground state of the problem, and the statistical average should not be taken over this irrelevant ground state. We should choose instead the statistical average over the Bogoliubov's quasiparticles $\gamma$. Namely, one has

$$\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\rangle =\text{Tr}\left\{ e^{-\varepsilon_{n}\gamma_{n}^{\dagger}\gamma_{n}}c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\} \neq0$$

and this quantity is not zero, as you can check when writing the $c$'s in term of the $\gamma$'s. Importantly, note that the Wick's theorem can be prove rigorously for this statistical operator (see above).

This complete the proof that the mean-field approximation can be made rigorous, and that one can take the quantity $\left\langle c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right\rangle$ as the order parameter of a phase whose ground state is not filled with free electrons, but with Bogoliubov quasi-particles generated by the $\gamma$ operators. One usually refers to this ground state as the Cooper sea. If you expand the exponential with the $\gamma$'s over the zero-electron state noted $\left|0\right\rangle $, you will see you end up with something like $e^{-\sum\epsilon_{n}\gamma_{n}^{\dagger}\gamma_{n}}\left|0\right\rangle \sim\prod\left(u+vc_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}\right)\left|0\right\rangle $ which is the BCS Ansatz. Using rigorous notations you can make a rigorous proof of this last statement.

Now if you want to make the derivation completely rigorous, it requires to demonstrate the Wick's theorem, to manipulate the mean-field Hamiltonian in order to show the Bogoliubov mean-field transformation works quite well, and to calculate the statistical average over the Bogoliubov ground state. This goes straightforwardly ... over many many pages which I'm too lazy to write here.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer the question : Why do we have to enlarge the number
of possibilities for the ground state ? I guess this is at the heart of
your problem. Before doing so, let us quickly discuss the notion of ground state itself, which are called Fermi sea in the case of fermion.

## At the beginning: the Fermi surface or quasiparticles

So at the beginning is a collection of fermions, and the notion of Fermi
surface. An important element of the forthcoming discussion is the notion of [quasiparticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle). In condensed matter systems, the Fermi surface is *not* built from free electrons, or bare electrons, or genuine electrons. To understand how this notion comes in, let's take a free electron, i.e. a particle following the Dirac equation with charge $e$ and spin $1/2$, and put it into any material (say a semi-conductor or a metal for instance). By *electrons* any condensed matter physicist means that in a complex system (s)he studies, it is impossible to take into account all the possible interactions acting on the bare electron. Most of the interaction will be of bosonic nature (think especially about phonons). So one hopes that taking all the complicated bosonic interactions on the fermionic bare electron results in a composite particle which still has a fermionic statistics, and hopefully behaves as a Schrödinger equation, possibly with kinetic energy $E_{c}=\dfrac{p^{2}}{2m_{2}^{*}}+\dfrac{p^{4}}{4m_{4}^{*}}+\cdots$ with effective masses $m_{2}^{*}$ that one can suppose $p$-independent and possibly $m_{2}^{*}\ll m_{4}^{*}$, such that one has the usual Schrödinger equation.

Note that

- the Schrödinger equation is anyways invariant with respect to the statistics of the particle it describes
- the above construction can be made a bit more rigorous using the tools of effective field theory and renormalisation

The important thing is that these *electrons* are still fermions, and so they pile up to form a Fermi sea. From now on we write electrons or quasiparticle without making distinction, since in condensed matter there is only quasiparticle. A quasiparticle of charge $e$ and spin $1/2$ will be called an electron. A Fermi surface is a stable object, as has been discussed [in an other
question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69358/16689). Stable ? Well, not with respect to the Cooper mechanism,
which allows bound states of electrons to be generated on top of a Fermi
sea. These bound states are of charge $2e$ and their total spin makes
them some kind of bosons. They are as well quasiparticles, but we will call them Cooper pairs, instead of quasiparticle of charge $2e$ and spin $1$ or $0$.

Now we identified the ground state of a metal as a Fermi sea of fermionic quasiparticles called electrons, we can try to understand how this ground state becomes unstable and why we should then take into account several ground states, of possibly different statistical nature, as the bosonic versus fermionic ground state in a superconductor. The reason why we need to enlarge the available ground states is clearly
due to the symmetry breaking, as we review now.

## Symmetry breaking and space of ground states

First, think about the para-ferromagnetic transition. Before the
transition (paramagnetic phase) you can choose the orientation of the
spin the way you want: they are random in the electron gas. A nice
picture about that is to say: the Fermi surface is just the same for all
the electrons.

Now comes the ferromagnetic phase: the system chooses either to align
all the spins in the up or down direction (of course the direction is
not fixed and the system is still rotationally invariant unless a
magnetic field is applied, but clearly the electron spins are
polarised). What about the Fermi surface ? Well, it becomes two-fold ...
There is now one Fermi surface for the spin-up electrons and one Fermi
surface for the spin-down electron. So the number of available ground
states increases.

The link to the symmetry breaking is clear: the more you want of
symmetries, the less possible states you allow. Say in the other way:
breaking the symmetry allows for more states to exist. This is also
quite straightforward from the following argument: once you allow an
interaction responsible for the parra-to-ferro transition, you must
first answer the question: is the unpolarised Fermi surface or one of
the polarised Fermi surfaces the true ground state ? So you need a way to
compare the spin-unpolarised and the spin-polarised ground states. So
clearly the number of accessible ground states must be greater once a
phase transition and a symmetry breaking is under the scope.

Now, about superconductivity and the relation to symmetry breaking, I
refer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69490/16689) (about particle number conservation) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133780)
(about the $\text{U }\left(1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ symmetry
breaking in superconductors) answers. The important thing is that the
Cooper mechanism makes the Fermi surface instable. What results ? A kind
of Bose-Einstein condensate of charged particles (the Cooper pairs of
charge $2e$) and some electrons still forming a Fermi-Dirac condensate
and so a Fermi sea, with less fermions than before the transition (hence
the number of electrons is not conserved). So now the available ground
states are i) the genuine Fermi sea made of electrons, ii) the charged
Bose-Einstein condensate made with all the electrons paired up via
Cooper mechanism and iii) a mixture of the two Fermi-Dirac and
Bose-Einstein condensates (be careful, the terminology is misleading, a
Bose-Einstein condensate and a Cooper pair condensate are not really the
same thing).

Unfortunately, the real ground state is a kind of mixture, but at
zero-temperature, one might suppose that all the conduction electrons
have been transformed in Cooper pairs (in particular, this can not be
true if one has an odd number of electrons to start with, but let forget
about that). Let us call this complicated mixture the Cooper
condensate, for simplicity.

In any case, we have to compare the Fermi sea with the Cooper
pairs condensate. That's precisely what we do by supposing a term like $\left\langle
cc\right\rangle \neq0$.

## A bit of mathematics

We define a correlation as $\left\langle c_{1}c_{2}\right\rangle $ with
creation or annihilation operators. In a paramagnetic phase, we have
$$\left\langle N\right|c^{\dagger}c\left|N\right\rangle =\left\langle
n_{\uparrow}\right|c_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}c_{\uparrow}\left|n_{\uparrow}\right\rangle +\left\langle
n_{\downarrow}\right|c_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}c_{\downarrow}\left|n_{\downarrow}\right\rangle $$ as the only non-vanishing correlation, with
$\left|N\right\rangle$ a Fermi sea filled with $N$ electrons. Note in
that case the polarised Fermi seas
$\left|n_{\uparrow,\downarrow}\right\rangle$ make no sense, since there
is no need for an internal degree of freedom associated to the
electrons ; or these two seas are the two shores of the unpolarised Fermi ocean... Now, in the ferromagnetic phase, the correlations
$\left\langle
n_{\uparrow}\right|c_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}c_{\uparrow}\left|n_{\uparrow}\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle
n_{\downarrow}\right|c_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}c_{\downarrow}\left|n_{ \downarrow}\right\rangle$ starts to make sense individually, and the ground states
with polarised electrons as well. In addition, we must compare all of
these inequivalent ground states. One way to compare all the possible
ground states is to construct the matrix $$\left\langle
\begin{array}{cc} c_{\uparrow}c_{\downarrow}^{\dagger} &
c_{\uparrow}c_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}\\
c_{\downarrow}c_{\downarrow}^{\dagger} &
c_{\downarrow}c_{\uparrow}^{\dagger} \end{array}\right\rangle
=\left\langle \left(\begin{array}{c} c_{\uparrow}\\ c_{\downarrow}
\end{array}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{array}{cc}
c_{\downarrow}^{\dagger} &
c_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}\end{array}\right)\right\rangle $$ where the
ground state is a bit sloppily defined (i.e. I did not refer to
$\left|n_{\uparrow,\downarrow}\right\rangle$, and I simply put the
global $\left\langle \cdots\right\rangle $ for simplicity). The fact
that the construction is a tensor product (the symbol $\otimes$ in the
right-hand-side just does what appears in the left-hand-side) clearly
shows that you can restaure the different ground states as you wish. In
a sense, the problem of defining the different ground states is now put
under the carpet, and you just have to deal with the above matrix.
Clearly the diagonal elements exist only in the paramagnetic phase and
the off-diagonal elements exists only in the ferromagnetic case, but
this is no more a trouble, since we defined a tensorial product of
several ground states and we are asking: which one is the good one?

Now, for the superconductor, one does not polarise the spins of the
electrons, one creates some bosonic correlations on top of two fermionic
excitations. So the natural choice for the matrix is $$\left\langle
\begin{array}{cc} cc^{\dagger} & cc\\ c^{\dagger}c^{\dagger} &
c^{\dagger}c \end{array}\right\rangle =\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{c} c\\ c^{\dagger}
\end{array}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{array}{cc} c^{\dagger} &
c\end{array}\right)\right\rangle $$ where still, the diagonal part
exists already in a simple metal, and the off-diagonal shows up once the
system transits to the superconducting phase. Clearly, if you call
$\left|N\right\rangle $ the Fermi-Dirac condensate with $N$ electron of
charge $e$, and $c$ the operator destroying an electron in this Fermi
sea, then you must define $\left\langle cc\right\rangle \equiv\left\langle N-2\right|cc\left|N\right\rangle \propto\left\langle N\right|cc\left|N+2\right\rangle \propto\left\langle N-1\right|cc\left|N+1\right\rangle $ (note you can do the way you want, and this has profound implications for Josephson physics, but this is not the story today) for the correlation to exist. What are the states $\left|N-2\right\rangle $ then ? Well, it is clear from the context: a Fermi sea with two electrons removed. Without the Cooper mechanism, we would have no idea what is this beast, but thanks to him, we know this is just the instable Fermi sea with one Cooper pair removed due to the action of a virtual phonon.

Whereas the parra-ferromagnetic transition was seen in the competition
between unpolarised versus polarised spins, the normal-superconducting
transition can be seen in the competition between particle and hole
versus particle-hole mixtures.

## About the mean-field construction

Now, how do we construct the mean-field Hamiltonian ? We simply use the
two body interaction term, and we apply the [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem). That is,
one does $$\left\langle
c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}^{\dagger}c_{4}^{\dagger}\right\rangle =\left\langle
c_{1}c_{2}\right\rangle \left\langle
c_{3}^{\dagger}c_{4}^{\dagger}\right\rangle -\left\langle
c_{1}c_{3}^{\dagger}\right\rangle \left\langle
c_{2}c_{4}^{\dagger}\right\rangle +\left\langle
c_{1}c_{4}^{\dagger}\right\rangle \left\langle
c_{2}c_{3}^{\dagger}\right\rangle $$ valid for any average taken over
Gaussian states. Clearly, one has (replace the numbers by spin vectors
eventually) : the Cooper pairing terms, the Heisenberg-ferromagnetic
coupling and some anti-ferromagnetic coupling (not discussed here).
Usually, since a system realises one ground state, we do not need to try
all the different channels. For superconductivity we keep the first term
on the right-hand-side.

As explained in many other pages, the mean-field treatment can be
justified carefully in the case of conventional superconductivity. See
e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257500/16689), or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298327/16689) questions, or [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/306541/16689) (on this
page).

Comment: This is something I'm going to have to go over a few times to fully understand, I think. But I still don't understand why we're suddenly taking the expectation values as $\langle N-2 |cc|N\rangle$, when in general expectation values and mean fields are always defined relative to a single state. I also don't understand why we consider a state with a cooper pair to have two fewer electrons than a state with no cooper pair--surely if you count the electrons using the number operator $\sum c^\dagger c$ you'll get the same answer regardless of whether the electrons have formed a pair?

Comment: *expectation values and mean fields are always defined relative to a single state* : well, superconductivity theory tells you that it is not *always* true for mean field. So, either you change the nomenclature, and no more call the BCS treatment a mean-field treatment. After all, you can name things the way you want, and *BCS method* could be used indeed. What I've tried to explain is that both $\left|N\right\rangle$ and $\left|N+2\right\rangle$ are in the same class of solutions/ground-states: they are both Fermi seas, but the second one has 2 *electrons* more. This ground-state is reachable.

Comment: *I also don't understand why we consider a state with a cooper pair to have two fewer electrons than a state with no cooper pair ...* if you do not understand this, you misunderstand the basic concept of quasiparticles in condensed matter problems. Condensed matter physicists **NEVER** discuss electrons as in quantum field theory, they discuss excitations on top of exotic ground states, called quasiparticles. The two simplest quantum ground states are the Fermi-Dirac sea and the Bose-Einstein condensate.

Comment: Somehow both quantum distributions appear in normal-superconductor phase transition, and so let us suppose they do. When you loose two fermions, you may get one boson. This mechanism is called Cooper instability. Not all materials present a Cooper instability of course. The important thing is: $c^{\dagger}c$ does *not* count the number of electrons, it counts the number of fermion modes, and $cc$ counts the Cooper-pairing generated bosons, so he number of boson modes. So in fact by Cooper pairing you loose two fermions and get one Cooper-pair/one boson.

Comment: The total number of charge is the same in both the normal and superconducting states. The crucial question is: how may we count them, because clearly $c^{\dagger}c$ no more does the job. This is a hard question in quantum field theory, since the U(1) symmetry breaking also destroys the conventional way of defining current through Noether theorem. In the mean-field/BCS treatment of the problem, you may try to define current in other way, and you will get something like $c^{\dagger}c+\Delta cc$ (picturesquely speaking, there is a post on SE where someone derives the current in the BdG frame)

Comment: Obviously, if you start with a set of fermion creation operators, $N=\sum c^\dagger c$ will count the total number of electrons in your system, regardless of whether they have formed quasiparticles or are in a simple fermi sea state. That operator $N$ is the number operator for *every* possible state, including exotic states where fermions form quasiparticles. No?

Comment: The only times I've seen this not be the case is where the problem redefines the operators $c$ with, e.g., a particle hole transformation, so they only count excitations above the Fermi energy. But nowhere in your answer did you mention anything about a redefinition of the $c$. If they are the normal fermion operators, then $N$ just counts all the fermions, no other details needed. Or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: I never redefine $c$. I just say from the beginning that $c^{\dagger}c$  counts the number of fermion, not the number of charges. A fermion is not necessarily charged ... The way to count charge is a bit obscure in quantum field theory anyways. Also, I think you completely miss the notion of quasiparticle in condensed matter. And I'm sure that's the third time I mention it :-) See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle if not able to find it alone ... $c$ destroys a fermionic quasiparticle that everyone call electron but which are not genuine electrons and can then decay and fuse.

Comment: I completely understand the idea of quasiparticles. What I might be misunderstanding is what you've defined $c^\dagger$ to mean. I thought $c^\dagger$ was a fermion creation operator, in which case it counts both the number of electrons and the number of filled fermion modes, since electrons can only exists in fermion modes, regardless if they're paired into quasiparticles or not. I don't understand what you mean when you say $c^\dagger c$ no longer counts the number of charges. I'd need some math, not just words, to explain how that could be true.

Comment: For example, could you explicitly write down a state that has a set number of charges, but a different number of fermions? I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Well, this question is trivial, since a fermion is not necessarily charged, whereas bosons may be charged. So for instance a gas of uncharged fermions $\sum_{n=0}^{N}c^{\dagger}\left(k_{n}\right)\left|\phi\right\rangle $ has $N$ fermion mode and zero charge. An other example is a gas of charged bosons $\sum_{n=0}^{N}a^{\dagger}\left(k_{n}\right)\left|\phi\right\rangle $ which has $N$ charges but zero fermion ...

Comment: Your previous comment makes clear you do not understand the concept of quasiparticles ... *I thought $c$ was a fermion operator, in which case it counts both the number of electrons and the number of filled fermion modes, since electrons can only exists in fermion modes, regardless if they're paired into quasiparticles or not*. The electrons you start with are already quasiparticles called electrons (and not necessarily charged, though this requires complicated criteria). Cooper-pairs are an other example of quasi-particle. CC* count the number of quasiparticles called electrons.

Comment: But I'm interested in a superconductor that is made out of valence electrons of atoms. So my electrons all have charge $e$, and they move in a background of nuclei with charge $-ne$. And $c^\dagger c$ counts the number of electrons AND the number of charges (up to a constant offset of the background charge, which I'm ignoring).

Comment: No, $c^{\dagger}c$ counts the number of fermions, call them electrons if you want, and $ec^{\dagger}c$ counts the number of charges. Anyways, what's the problem with that ? It has nothing to do with your initial question. So finally, did you understood why the BCS treatment may be justify ?

Comment: I really don't. I still don't understand why you are allowed to do mean field theory using $|N\rangle$ and $|N-2\rangle$, or why you made the distinction between number of charges and number of fermions in the BCS theory.

Comment: Please read again my answer : in a para-ferro transition, one has to discuss the possibility that a non-polarisd particle becomes polarised. In the normal-superconducting phase transition, one has to discuss the possibility for 1e-charge fermionic quasiparticle to become 2e-charge bosonic quasiparticles.

Comment: I understand that. But the 2e-charge bosonic quasiparticle still is made up of electrons, which are still counted by the operator $\sum c^\dagger c$.

Comment: On which state do you apply this operator ? Mean-field/BCS Hamiltonian clearly does not commute with this operator, so its eigenstates are not eigenstates of the BCS ground state. In fact the ground state of a superconductor is a complicated superposition of Fermi sea and Cooper condensate. According to the BCS Ansatz the BCS ground state reads $\left|0\right\rangle =\prod_{k}\left(u_{k}+v_{k}^{\ast}c_{k}^{\dagger}c_{-k}^{\dagger}\right)\left|\emptyset\right\rangle $

Comment: Which is what I was asking about in the first place. How do you start with a Hamiltonian that commutes with the number operator and end up with a mean field Hamiltonian that does not? It's all find to say "the Ansatz doesn't have definite particle number," but if the Ansatz is justified through mean field theory the mean field approximation doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why do you talk about spin polarised ground states in the Heisenberg model, although the related Hamiltonian has a spin rotation symmetry ? This is spontaneous symmetry breaking, and I explain in length the reason why one needs to enlarge the available ground states once this mechanism is taken into account, and how you can do that. The problem with an operator $c^{\dagger}c$ is that $c$ is fermionic and thus anti-commutes, whereas the ground state is built on bosons, and should be built on operators which may commute. I cite a few answers where I explain this.

Comment: The mathematical rigorous answer about the mean field construction is the one I gave at the end of my answer above : it's the Wick theorem which allows you to consider thing like $\left\langle c_{1}c_{2}\right\rangle \left\langle c_{3}^{\dagger}c_{4}^{\dagger}\right\rangle $. It is the same construction for a ferromagnet, though the dominant contribution is an other one, say $\left\langle c_{1}c_{3}^{\dagger}\right\rangle \left\langle c_{2}c_{4}^{\dagger}\right\rangle $.

Comment: Ultimately, if you're studying superconductivity for the first time (especially if it's your first contact with the notion of quasi-particle, effective model, mean-field approximation, instability and spontaneous symmetry breaking, as it seems it is for you), perhaps it's simpler for everyone (including me since I'm loosing many hours to answer your numerous questions...) to accept the concept. It works how it is. You may find time later to explain and resolve carefully what you feel not at ease at first. It sometimes requires many years before answering such questions having many facets.

Comment: About the many facets of superconductivity : http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284957/16689. About the particle conservation in condensed matter (and superconductivity example) : http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69490/16689. About the fermionic symmetry of superconductivity : http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/62364/16689

Comment: This is not my first time encountering any of these things. I am trying to now "find time later to explain and resolve carefully what I feel not at east at first". I understand the idea of spontaneous symmetry breaking and Wick's theorem and quasiparticles. I've explained why I don't think you can spontaneously break particle number conservation, and why I don't see how the term $\langle cc\rangle\langle c^\dagger c^\dagger\rangle$ dominates when you do the mean field theory. At the end of the day, those are my confusions, which none of the linked answers address.

Comment: If you disallow breaking the fermionic mode conservation or why the Wick theorem does not give $\left\langle cc\right\rangle \left\langle c^{\dagger}c^{\dagger}\right\rangle $, then, either you leave in a world without superconductivity, or you start all your studies of superconductivity with the BCS Ansatz, and never use quantum field methods. Did you tried to discuss with a researcher in your lab ? A direct discussion would be simpler than long long repetitions of the same arguments. Anyways, if you do not accept all my arguments, how would you process to get superconductivity ?

Comment: And one more time, I never said that the number of charge is not conserved, I said that the number of fermion modes of the initial system (before switching on the Cooper pairing) is not the same as the final system (once superconducting state is reached and because some of the initial fermionic modes are now bounded to Cooper pairs). I would really appreciate if you stop using misleading term such that *particle number conservation*, since I strongly believe that you misinterpret particle and quasiparticle (one more time !)

Comment: Start with a gas of hydrogen nuclei and suppose these are fermions. Under some circonstances, they may fuse and become deuteron, which are bosons (two fermions seen as a single (quasi-)particle is a boson, right ?). A condensed matter physicist would say that the number of hydrogen nuclei is not conserved because some disappear to make deuteron, though in the process the number of protons (for instance) is conserved. That's exactly the same with Cooper pairs, the charge is conserved, not the number of fermions... Now try to treat this mechanism in term of mean-field, you will get BCS theory.

Comment: I don't really care if you call them two hydrogen or one deuteron, my point is that if $c^\dagger$ is the hydrogen nuclei creation operator, them  $\sum c^\dagger c$ counts them as two hydrogen, and $\sum cc$ would evaluate to zero expectation value, regardless of whether I happen to be able to define a bosonic deuteron creation operator.

Comment: Again, I'm not trying to come up with a new theory of superconductivity, I'm trying to understand why BCS works. I just wanted a justification for the mean field treatment.

Comment: Please tell me when you will have understood :-) I'd be happy to understand why you force expectation value to exist, and not correlation between different ground states.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the real ground state is a kind of mixture, but at zero-temperature, one might suppose that all the conduction electrons have been transformed in Cooper pairs " I am a bit confused by this sentence in your answer. Doesn't ground state always mean zero temperature?